# 504 TimeOut Errors Accessing Microsoft Graph Reports

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm constantly getting repeated `504 - Gateway Timeout` (after 15 seconds) when trying to access activation reports via Microsoft Graph.

Occasionally, the query succeeds, but often after 11-12 seconds.

The subsequent CSV data download can take close to a minute to download 401 bytes!

Something is clearly not working as it should:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting this question.  So we can see what's going on, can you please update your question with example client-request-id and timestamp pairs for the operations that you are getting timeouts for, and even for the ones that are taking > 10 seconds.  This will allow us to look through the trace logs.