# Error 504 while trying to download CSV through Microsoft Gateway

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have problem with below request:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/OneDriveActivity(view='Detail',period='D7')/content

It is very slow and unreliable... Sometimes it works but takes ~30 seconds to provide the result (CSV ~225 KB), and very often it does time out with Error 504 Gateway Timeout

My problem looks similar to this one but I opened a different question as I am not authorized to comment on this question:
[504 TimeOut Errors Accessing Microsoft Graph Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46670610/504-timeout-errors-accessing-microsoft-graph-reports)

@dan-kershaw-msft, as you offered in the other question, would you please have a look to my query. Here are details:

- Date → Mon, 16 Oct 2017 08:58:13 GMT
- Duration → 15011.5868
- client-request-id → 58541992-8df4-4685-b768-10e154fa9d82
- request-id → 58541992-8df4-4685-b768-10e154fa9d82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be improved since 10/19. Can you please give it a try and let us know?